# How to change the datetime format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in sql servr

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently working with existing table.
I want change the `datetime` format
from

```
2014-03-06 00:00:00.000
```

to

```
06-03-2014 00:00:00.000
```

in table

Answer (score 0):

Datetimes are stored without any particular format. The format is just applied when you display the data.

You can change the way you display a date in a particular query by using the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function:

```
SELECT GETDATE(), CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 105)
```

The question here, is why do you want to change it? Maybe its something your view should be doing instead.

Comment: hi, i changed the column datatype from varchar to datetime.it changed successfully in database but the formate like 2014-03-06 00:00:00.000.Now i need change the format dd-mm-year like this  06-03-2014 00:00:00.000

Comment: That is what I mean. There is no format on DateTime columns, format is applied when you display the data. So you need to change it/define it when displaying it.

Comment: Hai juan, i used this query from varchar to date time UPDATE tbl_Sample
SET travedate2 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),CONVERT(DATETIME, travedate,105)) i need for change the format. when i replace 105 to 103 it will display another format. could you suggest my requirement format

Comment: @KameshNaidu can you please read the following: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery The format the datetime is stored is not shown. The only thing you can show is how the Date time is shown, not stored. How are you showing it? A query? A form? A report? You must change it there not in the table.